# Why listIterator of SynchronizedList needs external synchronization by the user?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, java.util.concurrent

Please refer to the following java source code :

```
static class SynchronizedList<E>
extends SynchronizedCollection<E>
implements List<E> {

final List<E> list;

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    synchronized (mutex) {return list.equals(o);}
}
public int hashCode() {
    synchronized (mutex) {return list.hashCode();}
}

public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
    return list.listIterator(); //Must be manually synched by user
}
```

My question is why is the listIterator() not guarded by the mutex as with hashcode() and equals() method ? Why did they design it so that it requires external synchronization by the user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main usage of ListIterator is not in obtaining it , but actually iterating it over for visiting individual elements in the list. This is a stateful operation and is entirely done by the client and not by the class `SynchronizedList`. On the other hand , the methods `equals()` and `hashCode()` are entirely computed within the `SynchronizedList` and do not require client to do much expect to take the returned values. Synchronizing the method to **obtain** the iterator is not much helpful as user1252434 pointed out.

ListIterator is a classic example of using client-side locking as a strategy to ensure synchronization when the original class cannot provide for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you suggest:

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
    synchronized(mutex) { return list.listIterator(); }
}
```

That won't help much.

You'd synchronize the *creation* of the iterator itself, which might help against a few issues. But you won't synchronize the **use** of the iterator. Changes can still be made to the list while you hold the iterator and - implementation depending - may even cause it to fail, because the list may be in an invalid internal state temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possible reasons.

We have three different Implementation of `List` interface . One is `Vector` and other two are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

One reason is If we are dealing with `Vectors` then defiantly no `synchronization` is required on `Vector` because it is already thread-safe but if we are using `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` then we need to synchronize these Lists

Other reason is we can use `SynchronizedList`  class in `Single-Threaded` Application if they would have made `listIterator()` as `Synchronized` then this is performance hit by  unnecessary `thread-safety` even in `single-threaded` environment.